# Parsing complex JSON with $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've this JSON (don't know if it's string or object, you probably do):

```
{
   "palvelut":[
      {
         "palvelu_id":"1",
         "palvelu_nimi":"Perusteita ja varmuutta juhlameikkiin\t",
         "palvelu_kuvaus":"Koulutus kestää 2h, jonka aikana käydään läpi hyvä meikkipohja, kasvojen korostus, poskipunan laitto, klassinen silmien ehostus ja hienostunut mutta simppeli huulimeikki. Suosittelemme että otat oman meikkipussisi sisältöineen mukaan, tai ainakin meikit joita haluat oppia käyttämään. ",
         "palvelu_hinta":"10"
      }
   ],
   "ajat":[
      {
         "aika_id":"1",
         "aika_kello":"14.00",
         "aika_paivamaara":"18.11.2013",
         "aika_paikkoja":"5",
         "aika_palvelu":"1"
      },
      {
         "aika_id":"4",
         "aika_kello":"16.30",
         "aika_paivamaara":"18.11.2013",
         "aika_paikkoja":"5",
         "aika_palvelu":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I'm unable to do anything with it! Anything I try, I get undefined, [Object Object] or simply nothing.

For example, if I try to add options to a select field with the data from `ajat`, I simply get nothing.

```
alert(json.ajat.aika_id);
```

Alerts undefined.

How do I parse this with $.each?

Even the simpliest example produces nothing.

```
$.each(json, function (key, value) {
    alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(key + ": " + value);` to get better view of what you are getting.

Comment: Shouldn't it be alert(json.ajat[0].aika_id);

Comment: If you use a comma in your `console.log()`, you won't get empty `[Object object]` references: `console.log(key, value)`

Comment: Note: In Microsoft IE you need to activate the developer tools first - otherwise console.log will not be recognized by the browser.

Comment: I never use IE. I just check that my sites work in it. @Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json.ajat` contains an array (that's what square brackets represent), so you have to index it:

```
alert(json.ajat[0].aika_id);
```

or you can loop over it:

```
$.each(json.ajat, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + ": " + value);
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you! You see, as you can probably see, I'm not a javascript or json expert, this is the first time I actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a String, you need this to translate it into an Object:

```
json = eval('(' + json + ')');
```

When it was an Object, you will see that "json.ajat" is an Array so "json.ajat.aika_id" didn't work;

With $.each:

```
$.each(json.ajat, function(){alert(this.aika_id + ':' + this.aika_kello)});
```

Comment: As less as I know, I know not to use `eval`.

Comment: As they say: "Eval is evil!" Avoid to use it wherever you can. It provides a lot of attack surface for code injection. Use `$.parseJSON(jsonStr)` to convert it into an object or use the 2nd alternative `$.each` as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is another usage example,

```
var jsonObject = {
   "palvelut":[
      {
         "palvelu_id":"1",
         "palvelu_nimi":"Perusteita ja varmuutta juhlameikkiin\t",
         "palvelu_kuvaus":"Koulutus kestää 2h, jonka aikana käydään läpi hyvä meikkipohja, kasvojen korostus, poskipunan laitto, klassinen silmien ehostus ja hienostunut mutta simppeli huulimeikki. Suosittelemme että otat oman meikkipussisi sisältöineen mukaan, tai ainakin meikit joita haluat oppia käyttämään. ",
         "palvelu_hinta":"10"
      }
   ],
   "ajat":[
      {
         "aika_id":"1",
         "aika_kello":"14.00",
         "aika_paivamaara":"18.11.2013",
         "aika_paikkoja":"5",
         "aika_palvelu":"1"
      },
      {
         "aika_id":"4",
         "aika_kello":"16.30",
         "aika_paivamaara":"18.11.2013",
         "aika_paikkoja":"5",
         "aika_palvelu":"1"
      }
   ]
};

$.each(jsonObject.ajat, function(i,elem){
    console.log(i);
    console.log(elem);
});
```

followed by a fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/pQxRp/